# Using observable. Can someone explain to me how this code works

Tags: observable, angular2-observables

```
public SavePatientEducationDetails(patientEducation: any): Observable<any> {
  return new Observable<any>(obs => {
    this.http.post(environment.API.PATIENT_FAMILLY_EDUCATION + "?isNew=true", patientEducation).subscribe(res => {
      this.response = Object.assign(res);
      setTimeout(() => {
        obs.next(this.response);
        obs.complete();
      }, 500);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's a wrong implementation of using observable to begin with.

In this code, you start by creating a new observable:

```
new Observable<any>(obs => {});
```

In this observable, you make an http post request (probably to save some data) and you subscribe to it to get its response value:

```
new Observable<any>(obs => {
  this.http.post(environment.API.PATIENT_FAMILLY_EDUCATION + "?isNew=true", patientEducation).subscribe(res => {});
});
```

In the subscribe, you copy the response value to a new object with `this.response = Object.assign(res);`
Then, finally, after 500ms (thanks to the setTimeOut), you emit the response with `obs.next()` and complete the observable with (obviously) the `obs.complete()` method.
All this code does is juste adding 500ms to the post request, **which is already an observable**, so wrapping the request in a new observable is useless.

To me, you'll get exactly the same result by doing so:

```
public SavePatientEducationDetails(patientEducation: any): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(environment.API.PATIENT_FAMILLY_EDUCATION + "?isNew=true", patientEducation);
}
```

May be you can tell what was the original purpose of this code.